# JavaScript Array Key & Value

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to have a key and a value in JavaScript?

So for example in PHP you have "key" => "value", "key" => "value". Is there anyway to do that in JavaScript?

Comment: Suggest starting out with a basic JS tutorial. You could start with [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). By the way, `node.js` is just one implementation/environment for JavaScript. You question is about JavaScript, not node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use objects, like so:

```
var obj = {
    "key": "value",
    "otherkey": "othervalue"
};
```

And then you can get values from obj like this:

```
console.log(obj["key"]); // outputs "value"
```

And you can use dot notation instead of brackets if that's easier for you:

```
console.log(obj.key); // outputs "value"
```